# how to demote user privileges to run a script

Tags: privileges

I would like to run a script, started by snmptrapd, as a regular user.
Looks like the traphandle directive in /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf runs the indicated program as a privileged user (root:root).
The traphandle program is a bash script. Is there any way to drop privileges from root to a regular user, at beginning of execution/script ?
The traphandle program that I intend to run as regular user create files that would better if they were created as regular user.
Of course I can issued chmod/chown all over in the script for each file created, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following programs to drop permissions to that of some user account:

- [setuidgid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/setuidgid.8.html)

  ```
  setuidgid user /path/unprivileged.sh
  ```
- [chpst](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html)

  ```
  chpst -u user /path/unprivileged.sh
  ```

Comment: Great !! This is what I was looking for. Both are new to me, never heard about.
Thank you and best regards !

Comment: Sure ! I've tried to use the up arrow but my reputation is too low for now and I assumed the everything was disabled to me.

Comment: Thank you and good luck.